# Enumerating an associated type in a typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Given a typeclass definition like the following, I'd like to enumerate the `MyClassId a` type for any type that is an instance of `MyClass`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

class
  ( Enum (MyClassId e)
  , Bounded (MyClassId e))
  => MyClass e where
    type MyClassId e :: *

enumMyClassId :: MyClass a => [MyClassId a]
enumMyClassId = enumFrom minBound
```

However, when I try to compile this snippet of code, GHC 7.10.2 complains with the following message:

```
enumTypeClass.hs:12:18:
    Couldn't match type ‘MyClassId a0’ with ‘MyClassId a’
    NB: ‘MyClassId’ is a type function, and may not be injective
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Expected type: [MyClassId a]
      Actual type: [MyClassId a0]
    In the ambiguity check for the type signature for ‘enumMyClassId’:
      enumMyClassId :: forall a. MyClass a => [MyClassId a]
    To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
    In the type signature for ‘enumMyClassId’:
      enumMyClassId :: MyClass a => [MyClassId a]
```

I am not exactly sure why it can't infer that the `a` type variable is the same as the `a` in the constraint for the function `enumMyClassId`. One possible fix is to change the function `enumMyClassId` to the following:

```
enumMyClassId :: MyClass a => a -> [MyClassId a]
enumMyClassId _ = enumFrom minBound
```

But this is not very elegant as it introduces an unused variable just to make the program typecheck. Is there some solution that doesn't involve the trick above?

Comment: You may also like the [universe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe) family of packages, which offers `universe :: Universe a => [a]` as a canonical way to enumerate a given type. It has many instances that are not covered by the `(Enum a, Bounded a)` constraint -- and skips a few instances that would be covered by that, but in the wrong way, like `Double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your function is rejected is that any attempt to *use* it will result in ambiguity. At the use site, you can give a signature that constrains `MyClassId a`, but you can't specify `a`. You should be able to defer the error message to the use site (where it will be easier to understand) by temporarily enabling `AllowAmbiguousTypes`.

There are two idiomatic fixes:

#### Use a proxy

```
enumMyClassId :: MyClass a => proxy a -> [MyClassId a]
```

You'd typically pass this a `Proxy` from `Data.Proxy`, but you can also use an arbitrary value whose type's last argument is `a`.

#### Use a tagged type

This approach is typically less convenient, but sometimes is important for getting things to be memoized.

Edward Kmett's `tagged` package gives you

```
newtype Tagged s b = Tagged {unTagged :: b}
```

Then you'd write

```
enumMyClassId :: MyClass a => Tagged a [MyClassId a]
```

And call it

```
enumMyClassId :: Tagged a [MyClassId a]
```

---

There's also a GHC-special approach that's not even intended ever to be portable, but that gives performance like tagged types with proxy convenience.

#### Magic proxy

You can use the magical [`Proxy#` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#t:Proxy-35-) that GHC completely erases in compilation. This works just like the first solution, but uses a `Proxy# a` type instead of a `proxy a` one. When calling such a function, you pass `proxy#`, which is a totally fake value.

Comment: I would propose a third idiomatic solution, which is to move the constraint from the class instance to the type signature of `enumMyClassId`, e.g. `enumMyClassId :: (Bounded (MyClassId a), Enum (MyClassId a)) => [a]` and skip that constraint in the `MyClass` declaration.

Comment: @DanielWagner, sure, if you don't need/want that constraint for some other reason.